# Which is the better way to visually hide things, clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0) or visibility: hidden?

Tags: css, hide, visibility, clip, class-visibility

Recently, I saw some tricks on hiding things. What I'm curious about is what's the difference between `clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);` and `visibility: hidden;`, while both can hide things and remain the space in the same time.

Also, is there any difference between using `clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);` and `clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);`?

Comment: hiding stuff with visibility hidden will still take up space in the dom never seen anything hidden using clip before

Comment: [These are the ways I have hidden stuff](http://jsfiddle.net/xtoqLjpu/2/) - I usually go for the fixed position as it just pushes the content off the screen whilst not taking up and space in the dom

Answer (score 4):

Visually, a `clip`ped element is collapsed, just like an element with `display: none` is. `visibility: hidden` on the other hand reserves the space the element would normally use.

In other words, comparing `clip` and `visibility` is very much apples to oranges, you should be comparing `clip` and `display`.

I guess one reason to use one or the other is accessibility:

- `visibility: hidden` hides content from screenreaders.
- `display: none` hides content from screenreaders.
- `clip: rect(0,0,0,0); position: absolute` keeps content visible to screenreaders.

*Compatibility:* MDN marks `clip` as deprecated, with `clip-path` being the newer replacement.

Comment: There's no mention (now in 2022) that CSS `clip` is *"deprecated"*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip - although developers *are encouraged* to use `clip-path`.